# Accidentally deleted lampp folder BEFORE Uninstalling XAMPP from Ubuntu. How do I proceed with Uninstallation now?

Tags: php, ubuntu, xampp, lampp

OK so I wanted to execute the commands in the following sequence.

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop
sudo chmod +x /opt/lampp/uninstall
sudo /opt/lampp/uninstall
sudo rm -R /opt/lampp
```

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500684/completely-uninstall-xampp-if-not-installed-from-apt-get#answer-798635)

But I mistakenly executed **`sudo rm -rf /opt/lampp`** after `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop`. This removed the `lampp` director and so I can not execute the next commands now. (Because lampp is gone, along with its contents which includes the `uninstall` executables/files)

The purpose of this entire thing was to remove every trace of XAMPP from my Ubuntu machine. Because I want to install an Older version of XAMPP.

So what should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

According to a [thread on the Ubuntu forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=779970) you've already deleted XAMPP from your system, and the only thing remaining are some menu items. Which you can delete manually.

If that doesn't help, then you could simply re-install and then remove it properly.

Comment: "remaining are some menu items. Which you can delete manually" - what menu items? where do I find them. Need to remove every trace of Ubuntu.